# What is the best way to eliminate MS Visual C++ Linker warning : "warning LNK4221"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, suppress-warnings

I have a CPP source file that uses **#if** / **#endif** to compile out completely in certain builds.  However, this generates the following warning.

```
warning LNK4221: no public symbols found; archive member will be inaccessible
```

I was thinking about creating a macro to generate a dummy variable or function that wouldn't actually be used so this error would go away but I want to make sure that it doesn't cause problems such as using the macro in multiple files causing the linker to bomb on multiply defined symbols.

What is the best way to get rid of this warning (without simply suppressing the warning on the linker command line) ?

FWIW, I would be interested in knowing how to do it by suppressing the warning on the linker command line as well but all my attempts there appear to be simply ignored by the linker and still generate the error.

One other requirement: The fix must be able to stand up to individual file builds or unity build (combine CPP file builds) since one of our build configurations is a bulk build (like a unity build but groups of bulk files rather than a single master unity file).

Comment: What syntax for calling the linker have you tried (and it didn't work for you)?

Comment: I have tried "/ignore:4221" for linker and "#pragma warning(disable: 4221)" for the cpp file.  Neither worked.

Comment: As an aside - what's the purpose of the 'unity build'?

Comment: We develop using the Unreal Engine. Both our game studio (WB Games Chicago) and Epic have found that Bulk Builds (roughly 1 Unity Builds per system / directory) cut down on significantly on compile time and link time (~4X faster). They also aid the compiler to inline code better and generate faster performing code.  So we use Bulk Builds for Retail & Development builds but not for Full Debug builds.

Comment: As a side note, googling around, it seems that there's no documented or otherwise known way to disable VC linker warnings - `/ignore` is for VC6 only.

Comment: @Adisak -thanks for the info on the unity builds.

Comment: /ignore:4221 works fine for me, on Visual C++ 2005, where lib.exe identifies itself as version 8.00.50727.762. [Geoff Chappell](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/link/link/options/ignore.htm) writes it is indeed undocumented but used in public Microsoft material.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, the fix I am going to use is Pavel's suggestion with a minor tweak.  The reason I’m using this fix is it’s an easy macro to drop in and it will work in bulk-builds / unity-builds as well as normal builds:

Shared Header:

```
// The following macro "NoEmptyFile()" can be put into a file
// in order suppress the MS Visual C++ Linker warning 4221
//
// warning LNK4221: no public symbols found; archive member will be inaccessible
//
// This warning occurs on PC and XBOX when a file compiles out completely
// has no externally visible symbols which may be dependant on configuration
// #defines and options.

#define NoEmptyFile()   namespace { char NoEmptyFileDummy##__LINE__; }
```

File that may compile out completely:

```
NoEmptyFile()
#if DEBUG_OPTION
      // code
#endif // DEBUG_OPTION
```

Answer (score 20):

Use an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace { char dummy; };
```

Symbols within such namespace have external linkage, so there will be something in the export table. On the other hand, the namespace name itself will be distinct (you can think of it as "randomly generated") for every translation unit, so no clashes.

Comment: I'm going to test that out.  I need it to work with unity builds so I might have to make it a macro with "char dummy##__LINE__;" or something like that so I don't have replicated symbols within a single translation unit.

Comment: The fix here bombs on our unity build as expected, but it should work with the minor mod I described.

Comment: @GMan:  Our translation units vary whether or not we do a bulk build (similar to unity build).  You need to put this in each unit that could be empty.  However, the bulk builds will dynamically bind units at compilation time.

Comment: @Adisak, I'm still curious as to why it "bombs out", and why adding `__LINE__` changes that. Can you explain in some more detail?

Comment: I think that his "unity build" cats all the cpp files together and compiles them as a single translation unit. Hence `(anonymous)::dummy` is the same symbol in each and the compiler would complain about multiple definitions. His fix is to instead distinguish the `dummy` objects with `__LINE__`.

Comment: Ah, understood now. Okay; unfortunately, `extern char` won't help, since it's not really a definition, but effectively a forward declaration for a variable (which may, and indeed usually is, in another translation unit). It won't result in an entry in the exported symbols table.

Comment: @Steve: That's exactly right...except instead of cat, it generates a temp CPP file and #includes the other CPP files into it.  But the result is fundamentally the same... so +1.

Comment: @Pavel: yep, I realised that too. I must have replaced my comment as you were typing.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to @Adisak's answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823024/7733418 ) , I guess some additional macro expansion magic is useful:

```
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) x ## y
#define TOKENPASTE2(x, y) TOKENPASTE(x, y)
#define NONEMPTY_TRANSLATION_UNIT char TOKENPASTE2(NoEmptyFileDummy, __LINE__);
```

Comment: Please learn what a comment is, including that you do not yet have the privilege to do so and what an answer is. If you keep insisting that what can be seen as an answer is a comment, people might start believing you and start flagging your posts for deletion for violating the rules about not commenting wihtout the privilege. Elsewhere you posted similarily. The pattern indicates that you might benefit from reading the [tour] again. If you think that this only works as a comment on an existing answer please delete it and wait for the privilege.

Comment: I deleted that you consider this a comment, if you still do please delete this.